# Nested Table rows HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with a dynamic table where each line of this table is a person's reg and each person has a lot of files that must be shown below their reg. The following image is how the html table supposed to works:

[image: how table should work]

I'm using bootstrap 3.3 in my project and this is my HTML table code that is not working properly:

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Nome </th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><strong>#1</strong></td>
         <td>Peter Parker</td>
         <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"
               title=" Editar ">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
               <!-- Editar -->
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
            title=" Excluir ">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            <!-- Excluir -->
            </button>
         </td>
         <br><br>
         <table class="table table-hover">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>XLS</td>
                  <td>file1.xls</td>
                  <td></td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="line-height: 12.0;">
         <button class="btn btn-primary"
            type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalMembroFamiliar">
         <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
         Add New Member
         </button>
      </td>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

The above code is rendering the HTML table as following:

[image: how table is rendering]

How can I fix my code to make the table rendering like in the first image?

Answer (score 1):

Yout have to insert the "inner" table into a `<td>` tag.

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Nome </th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><strong>#1</strong></td>
         <td>Peter Parker</td>
         <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"
               title=" Editar ">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
               <!-- Editar -->
            </button>
            &nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
            title=" Excluir ">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            <!-- Excluir -->
            </button>
         </td>
         <td>
           <table class="table table-hover">
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>XLS</td>
                    <td>file1.xls</td>
                    <td></td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td style="line-height: 12.0;">
         <button class="btn btn-primary"
            type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalMembroFamiliar">
         <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
         Add New Member
         </button>
      </td>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

For more information, please review [HTML5.2: Tabular data](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/tabular-data.html#the-table-element)